# SQL prestashop stats order total by customers group

Tags: sql, prestashop

I try to export my order total by customers group in prestashop

This is my REQUEST for the group N° 3 for example:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(o.`total_paid_real`, 0 ) / cu.conversion_rate), 2) as totalMoneySpent
FROM `ps_orders` o
LEFT JOIN `ps_currency` cu ON o.id_currency = cu.id_currency
LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON c.id_default_group= 3
WHERE o.valid = 1;
```

OTHER VERSION (SAME RESULT, the total of all group)

```
SELECT ROUND( SUM( IFNULL(o.`total_paid_real`, 0 ) / cu.conversion_rate), 2 ) as totalMoneySpent
FROM `ps_orders` o
LEFT JOIN `ps_currency` cu ON o.id_currency = cu.id_currency
#LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON c.id_default_group=3
WHERE o.valid = 1 
AND o.id_customer IN( SELECT c.id_customer FROM `ps_customer` c  WHERE c.id_default_group=3 )
 ;
```

My problem is that c.id_default_group never change the results,

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know anything about prestashop, but you can provide some example data from your tables and your expected result and you might get more help from the community (even from people that don't know prestashop) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.group_id, ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(o.`total_paid_real`, 0 ) / cu.conversion_rate), 2) as totalMoneySpent
FROM `ps_orders` o
LEFT JOIN `ps_currency` cu ON o.id_currency = cu.id_currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you apply the aggregate function `SUM` you have to `GROUP BY` in order to get the aggregate result for a number of rows (otherwise the aggregate is applied individually for each row, defeating its own purpose).

```
SELECT c.group_id, ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(o.`total_paid_real`, 0 ) / cu.conversion_rate), 2) as totalMoneySpent
FROM `ps_orders` o
LEFT JOIN `ps_currency` cu ON o.id_currency = cu.id_currency
LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON c.id_default_group= 3
WHERE o.valid = 1
GROUP BY c.group
ORDER BY c.group
```

assuming `group_id` identifies the customer group you refer to in the question.